# Which of the following equivalence classes are equal?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations, congruence-relations

Let R be the relation of congruence modulo 3. Which of the following equivalence classes are equal.

```
[7], [-4], [-6], [17], [4], [27], [19]
```

The answer is: [7]=[4]=[19],[−4]=[17],[−6]=[27]. I just don't understand why the answer is this. How and why do we create relationships based on these numbers?

Comment: Do you know what it means for two numbers to be congruent modulo $3$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Is it where there's a relationship R, and there are integers m and n, where 3 | (m - n)? I understand modulo 3 we are dividing by 3 with modulo 3, but with congruency are we always subtracting m with n?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig So the reason why there's a relationship in let's say for example, [7] = [4] = [19], is because we can subtract either or and we would still get an answer that gets divided by 3 whole?

Comment: The numbers in the equivalence class $[7]$ are all the integers with remainder $1$ when divided by $3$.  This is also true for $[4]$ and $[19]$, so those three equivalence classes are equal.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig So what is the m - n for? Why don't we have -4 in that relationship as well?

Comment: $m \equiv n \pmod{3} \iff m - n = 3k, k \in \mathbb{Z}$.  This means that $m$ and $n$ differ by an integer multiple of $3$.  As you can see from my answer, the equivalence classes modulo $3$ correspond to the numbers that have the same remainder when divided by $3$.  Since $7$, $4$, and $19$ all have remainder $1$ when divided by $3$, they are in the same equivalence class.  The number $-4$ has remainder $2$ when divided by $3$, so it is in a different equivalence class than $4$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I've got it! One last question. If this was modulo 5, would the multiples differ by 5 instead of 3?

Comment: That is also correct.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, $a \equiv b \mod{3} \iff a - b = 3n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.  What this means is that two integers are equivalent modulo $3$ if they have the same remainder when divided by $3$.

By definition, $[7] = \{k \in \mathbb{Z} \mid 7 - k = 3n, n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.  Thus, the numbers in this equivalence class differ from $7$ by a multiple of $3$.  Hence, 
$$[7] = \{\ldots, -11, -8, -5, -2, 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, \ldots\}$$
Notice that $[7]$ is the set of all integers that have remainder $1$ when divided by $3$.  The same is true for $[4]$ and $[19]$.  Therefore, $[4] = [7] = [19] = [1]$.

The relationship $a \equiv b \pmod{3}$ partitions all integers into three equivalence classes, those with remainder $0$ when divided by $3$, those with remainder $1$ when divided by $3$, and those with remainder $2$ when divided by $3$.

Notice that those numbers in the equivalence classes $[-6]$ and $[27]$ have remainder $0$ when divided by $3$.  Hence, $[-6] = [27] = [0]$.

The numbers in the equivalence classes $[-4]$ and $[17]$ have remainder $2$ when divided by $3$.  Hence, $[-4] = [17] = [2]$.